# Is there any JSON like object in Java?

Tags: java

In C#, you can do

```
var cat=new {amount=4,sound="mouw",food="fish"};
```

then you do

```
print("My cat ate "+cat.food+" "+cat.amount+"es");
```

Then it will print

```
My cat ate 4 fishes
```

Is there something cool like this Java?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are Objects. You can define them yourself such as,

```
class Cat {
    int amount;
    String sound;
    String food;

    Cat(int amount, String sound, String food) {
       this.amount = amount;
       this.sound = sound;
       this.food = food;
    }
}
```

Then have a main class,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat(4, "mouw", "fish");
        System.out.println("My cat ate " + cat.amount + " " + cat.amount + "es");
    }
}
```

Here is a good resource to get you started:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Defining a named class for each individual is cumbersome. If there are 100 objects need to be used in a method, defining a class for each of them is not the best idea although it is doable (in bean pattern or not). I guess Java lacks this capability.

Comment: Using the animal example that you gave, I would look into abstract classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

It would help reduce the amount of code that you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

[Project Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) will introduce [Value Types](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169) to the language, but we won't get this yet in Java 9. Since you are using the var keyword, I also want to refer to [JEP-286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) about local variable type inference. These are all not (yet) available in Java.

Maybe I misinterpreted your question and you are just looking for Plain Old Java Objects instead, then the answer of [user123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327636/user123) will help you out.